# ModelState is invalid

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a ASP.NET Core MVC project for book library and I am trying to create a model with relationships from a form.

I made this Loan model and controller with views with the scaffolding feature

```
public class Loan
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Book")]
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public virtual Book Book { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Reader")]
    public int ReaderId { get; set; }
    public virtual Reader Reader { get; set; }
}

public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,DueDate,BookId,ReaderId")] Loan loan)
{
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(loan);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }

        ViewData["BookId"] = new SelectList(_context.Book, "Id", "Id", loan.BookId);
        ViewData["ReaderId"] = new SelectList(_context.Reader, "Id", "Id", loan.ReaderId);

        return View(loan);
}
```

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="DueDate" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="DueDate" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="DueDate" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="BookId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="BookId" class ="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.BookId"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ReaderId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="ReaderId" class ="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.ReaderId"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I try to create new loan the loan.Book and loan.Reader is null.
So I tried to change the Create method like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,DueDate,BookId,ReaderId")] Loan loan)
{
        loan.Book = _context.Book.FirstOrDefault(b => b.Id == loan.BookId);
        loan.Reader = _context.Reader.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Id == loan.ReaderId);

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(loan);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }

        ViewData["BookId"] = new SelectList(_context.Book, "Id", "Id", loan.BookId);
        ViewData["ReaderId"] = new SelectList(_context.Reader, "Id", "Id", loan.ReaderId);

        return View(loan);
}
```

It sets the book and reader but the `ModelState` is still invalid:

[loan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQD9P.png)

[ModelState](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AP44b.png)

Comment: Add a ? to the Reader.  change it to public virtual Reader? Reader { get; set; }

Answer (score 0):

Entities represent data state. They should not be transferred between server and view as view state as that is not their primary purpose. I highly recommend using a POCO ViewModel to serve as view state. This helps minimize the amount of data being sent back and forth, and keeps you grounded in the expectation of what a view is actually sending back. If you use an entity as the DTO/ViewModel back from the view, it is only as complete as the client HTML can provide with the POST. It is *not* the entity that you might have sent, or something that can be trusted to be a complete and valid entity.

For something like a Create action we can use something like a CreateLoanViewModel if we are using asynchronous operations like AJAX:

```
public class CreateLoanViewModel
{
    public int? LoanId { get; set; }
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public int ReaderId { get; set; }
    public DateTime DueDate { get; set; } 
}
```

This makes it clear when doing the POST call that the view is simply passing the data needed to create the Loan:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,BookId,ReaderId,DueDate")] CreateLoanViewModel loanVM)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
       return View(loanVM);

    var book = _context.Book.Single(b => b.Id == loan.BookId);
    // TODO: Verify that this book is actually available to lend...
    var reader = _context.Reader.Single(r => r.Id == loan.ReaderId);

    var loan = new Loan
    {  
         Book = book,
         Reader = reader,
         DueDate = loanVM.DueDate // Consider calculating here rather than accepting from view.
    };
    _context.Add(loan);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
}
```

While it may seem unnecessary to create a new class when the Entity has these fields declared, often the view model does not need the overhead of all fields in the entity, as well as avoid any issues with things like serializers tripping lazy loads. It also avoids any misconception that the passed in object is nothing more than a container for data values we will use to create or update real entities. The data coming in cannot be assumed to be a complete entity, nor can it be trusted not to be tampered with.